# All topologies on $X=\{ a,b \}$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to find the possible topologies on $X=\{ a,b \}$.

1. $\varnothing ,\{ a,b \}$
2. $\varnothing ,\{ a \},\{ a,b \}$
3. $\varnothing ,\{ b \},\{ a,b \}$
4. $\varnothing ,\{ a \},\{ b \},\{ a,b \}$

First off, a topology $\tau $ on a set $X$ consists of subsets of $X$ following the properties:

1. The empty set $\varnothing$ and the space $X$ are both sets in the topology.
2. The union of any collection of sets in $\tau$ is contained in $\tau$.
3. The intersection of any finitely many sets in $\tau$ is also contained in $\tau$

All four I think are actual topologies. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A topology is a collection of subsets satisfying the three conditions you posted. For a set $X$, any topology of $X$ must contain both $\phi$ and $X$, and in particular, the collection $\tau_0 = \{\phi , X \}$ is always a topology.

The four collections of subsets you listed:

1. $\phi , \{a,b\}$
2. $\phi , \{a\} , \{a,b\}$
3. $\phi , \{b\} , \{a,b\}$
4. $\phi , \{a\} , \{b\} , \{a,b\}$

are indeed topologies, and these are the only possible topologies on $X = \{a,b\}$. You can (and should) verify that these are actually topologies (i.e. that they satisfy the definition of a topology).

Comment: I get it now. I have to verify whether the four collection of subsets are indeed topologies.

Comment: Yep. Note that the situation is somewhat easier with a set with two elements, because every collection of subsets containing $\phi,X$ is a topology. This is not true for sets with more elements. For instance, if you have $X = \{ a,b,c\}$, not every collection of subsets containing $\phi,X$ will be a topology. An example is $\phi, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b,c\}$. Can you see why this is not a topology on $X = \{a,b,c\}$?

Comment: I see. I find all four are actual topologies since they satisfy the definition.

Comment: To write $\emptyset$, use \emptyset. $\emptyset\neq\phi$.